# A good way to import tweets, blogpost, flickr photos, slideshare,

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm building a "social corner" on my website and I need to import quite a lot.

I've got these accounts:

- Twitter
- 2 blog
- Slideshare
- Flickr
- YouTube channel

I'm using the feeds-module at this moment, but for some reason, it got overwritten.

I tried with the Media module, but I got an error every time I tried to activate the modues, so that's not an option either.

There is a pretty good module for catching and showing tweets, but there seems none like it for YouTube posts, Slideshare, Blogs, Flickr,...

What is, in your opinion, the best way to import this kind of social media every 30 minutes or so. Because I can't think of any anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track, but it sounds like your site may have some "too many modules" issues.  If you're having modules randomly overwritten or enabling is throwing errors, it is usually time to clean up the site.  If you can, start with a brand new site and **only** enable the modules you absolutely need.  Keep things as basic as possible.  If you want to try out other modules do it on a separate "sandbox" site that is just for testing.

There isn't going to be a single-solution for all social media.  However some places to get started:

- [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) - for anything using RSS ([YouTube does](http://vdo.me/youtube-rss-feed-for-you-channel/), so [does SlideShare](http://help.slideshare.com/entries/20463203-how-can-i-subscribe-to-rss-feeds-on-slideshare), [Twitter kinda does](http://www.twittertorss.com/), etc)
- Specific modules could be used too like [Twitter Pull](http://drupal.org/project/twitter_pull) and the Media module as you mentioned.

Comment: I'll try to clean up my modules. You're right, it's an awe full long list! So I'll be in touch :)

Comment: Great!  Drupal is awesome because there are so many modules, but you can run into conflicts and sometimes some modules just are not written very well.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome. I had over 60 modules enabled and it seems like one of them one the malefactor! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) (with [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex)) is a very flexible option to achieve that (you should be able to import almost everything you need if you set it up properly). However, it may be a bit complex if content managers are expected to change its settings.

[Social Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_content) is far more limited (and still in beta), but provides a centralized user interface to set imports of the following networks:

- Twitter
- Instagram
- Facebook
- Tumblr
- Linkedin
- Youtube
- Flickr
- Pinterest